# Double Switch to Triple Switch - 2 Hot Wires

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a bathroom switch that powers two light fixtures from one set of wires (line, load, [image]ground). I added a vent fan and wanted my electrician to wire them together into a triple switch.

He says it can't be done because we have an extra hot wire and he tried to pigtail the two hot wires together into the switch but it tripped.

How should this be wired? I've taken a pic of the way existing double switch and the other incoming 14/2 white romex wire is in the back unconnected.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Can you get a better picture into the back of the box showing where all the wires go, please.

Comment: Added a pic of the back of the box showing all the wires as requested. Right side goes to GFCI. Then on the left side is the existing wiring for the double switch and the white newly run romex that is currently disconnected.

Comment: What's hidden in that mass of red tape? Why is that wire taped blue? Where is the ground wire coming out of the yellow cable - is it twisted with the ground from the white cable at the top of the box?

Comment: The grounds are connected together. This is an old house that I just bought so I don't know about the blue tape except perhaps it was to distinguish which light is which. There's nothing behind the red tape. The electrician just left it there and I didn't take it out. These are all on the same breaker. Shouldn't I be able to pigtail the two hots together together and connect them to the hot of the triple switch? The triple switch has 5 connectors - 3 loads for each device/light, 1 hot, and 1 ground.

Comment: What is the switch on the right all about?  What is the seemingly new 14/2 Romex with the black & white tied and taped?   Is the breaker 15A or 20A?  Is there a **white** wire in the yellow Romex cable?

Comment: There is no switch on the right, it's a GFCI. Yes, there are actual 3 pairs coming into this box. One goes to the GFCI on the right. Then there are two other romex wires coming in - one that is wired to the double switch (one hot wire) and one that is currently not wired to the switch. I want to wire all 3 into one switch and I have a triple switch is supposed to be able to control 3 separate devices.  I should be able to pigtail the two hots together but it trips. Why is that? They are on the same breaker.

Comment: 2 separate hots may be on opposite legs thus when you connect them it is a short leg to leg. It would also be a code violation to run 2 cables the way you are trying.

Comment: Whatever I have here is what the electrician left me who didn't seem to know what he was doing. So it seems the pigtail works but it requires me to connect the white (neutral wire) from the fan to either the blue or the red wire which control the other two lights. Problem is, when I connect it, the fan turns on and stays on. There is no "switch". He says he wired the vent fan like you would to a normal standard switch and was intending to get the power from the double switch.

Comment: Is replacing the existing wiring an option? Can you post photos of the insides of the light fixture boxes involved please?

Comment: This is an old New Orleans house so figuring out how the wires are/where they go would be a nightmare. I would post a pic of the ceiling light wiring but it's 12.5 feet high!